# Symfony adding style to each input field

Tags: php, css, symfony, input, symfony-forms

I have a function, in Symfony2, that creates a form. Then I load it using twig and everything works fine.

The problem is that I would like to add style to each label and each input, separately, and I can only add style to the whole form.

```
private function createEditForm(Client $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ClientType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('client_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',

    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
```

Could I do it the way I'm doing it or do I have to rebuild the function so it doesn't create the form dynamically from an array?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the class rendered for example in your `ClientType` via something like this:

```
$builder->add('name' , 'text' , array( 'attr' => array( 'class' => 'nameInputField' ) ) );
```

Or you can add/override directly in your twig template as such:

```
{{ form_row(form.name, { 'attr': { 'class': 'nameInputField' }} ) }}
```

For advanced cases and re-usability refer to the form customization tutorial here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: :) Same answer, i deleted mine.

Comment: Thank you very much. The first solution solved the problem.
As we say in spanish "Ole!"

Comment: Very well. Please kindly accept the answer, so other people can find this solution as well.